# setting variables to add multiple items for xsl pdf invoice creator - errors

Tags: xml, xslt, pdf-generation

Thanks for the original comments and replies!

As requested I've edited the question and I've broken down my code to smaller chunks to make it easier to understand, and hopefully someone can work out where I am going wrong?

The CRM uses XSL v.1.0 to create custom pdf templates using fields from the database to create quotations, invoice and orders (using the same basic template and filtering dependent on document type).

For each type of document (quotation, order, invoice etc) there is a separate fields, so I was trying to filter on document type as well as total each line to check if the total was not zero (so I can add custom fields on the invoice layout if a discount applies)

This part of the code parses ok, but doesn't produce the right answers (see below)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xslt:stylesheet xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" xmlns:xslt="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xf="http://www.ecrion.com/xf/1.0" xmlns:xc="http://www.ecrion.com/2008/xc" xmlns:xfd="http://www.ecrion.com/xfd/1.0" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="date str">
  <xslt:output indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">


                <!-- == REGIONAL DISCOUNT == -->
        <xsl:variable name="regional_discount_1">
            <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="sum(/hash/order_line_items/*/additional_discount_1_percent[@amount &gt; 0]) &gt; 0">
                    <xsl:value-of select="1"/> 
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable> 

        <!-- == EARLY PAYMENT OR PRICE DISCOUNT == -->
        <xsl:variable name="price_discount">
            <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="sum(/hash/order_line_items/*/hash/discount_percent[@amount &gt; 0]) &gt; 0">
                    <xsl:value-of select="1"/> 
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>

        <!-- == TOTAL DISCOUNTS // NB BAND RELIEF NEEDS TWO COLUMNS == -->
        <xsl:variable name="total_discount_columns">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$regional_discount_1 + $price_discount = 0">
                    <xsl:value-of select="0"/> 
                </xsl:when>;
                <xsl:when test="$regional_discount_1 + $price_discount = 1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="1"/> 
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$regional_discount_1 + $price_discount = 2">
                    <xsl:value-of select="2"/> 
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$regional_discount_1 + $price_discount = 3">
                    <xsl:value-of select="3"/> 
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
```

However the code for this variable (@band_relief) doesn't parse in the CRM (but doesn't give any error messages!) as had to remove from the code so not sure what is wrong with this:

```
        <xsl:variable name="band_relief">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="(sum(/hash/cf_customer_quotation_line_item_band_relief) != 0 and /hash/text/Collection_Class_Name = &quot;Private::Accounting::Quotation&quot;)
                or (sum(/hash/cf_customer_order_line_item_band_relief) != 0 and /hash/text/Collection_Class_Name = &quot;Private::Accounting::SalesOrder&quot;)
                or (sum(/hash/cf_customer_invoice_line_item_band_relief) != 0 and /hash/text/Collection_Class_Name = &quot;Private::Invoice:Quotation&quot;)
                or (sum(/hash/cf_customer_credit_note_line_item_band_relief) != 0 and /hash/text/Collection_Class_Name = &quot;Private::CreditNote::Quotation&quot;)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="1"/> 
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
```

If any of the product lines has one of the three discounts, I want the variable to be shown as 1, else 0 so I can add additional columns to the invoice layout.

Using the code below I've managed to extract the data from the three invoice line items and there is a discount of each type but on different product, however the variable @band_relief doesn't parse at all though I can still extract data as showed below.

```
  <fo:block padding-top="0.45cm" font-size="9pt" padding-bottom="0cm">
       <fo:inline>
        $regional_discount_1 <xsl:value-of select="$regional_discount_1"/>
        $price_discount <xsl:value-of select="$price_discount"/>
        </fo:inline>
     </fo:block>
     <fo:block padding-top="0.45cm" font-size="9pt" padding-bottom="0cm">
        <xsl:for-each select = "/hash/order_line_items/order_line_item">
        <fo:block padding-top="0.45cm" font-size="9pt" padding-bottom="0cm">
        <fo:inline>
        Band Relief <xsl:value-of select="sum(cf_customer_invoice_line_item_band_relief/@amount)"/>
        Regional Discount <xsl:value-of select="sum(additional_discount_1_percent)"/>
        Price Discount <xsl:value-of select="sum(discount_percent)"/>
        </fo:inline>
        </fo:block>
        </xsl:for-each> 
      </fo:block>
```

which produces the following outputs on the pdf:

Data

Band Relief 302.5  Regional Discount 50 Price Discount 0

Band Relief 10  Regional Discount 0 Price Discount 0

Band Relief 0   Regional Discount 0 Price Discount 5

Actual results:

$band_relief (Doesn’t work) $regional_discount 0    $price_discount 0

Expected (as discount exists!)

$band_relief 1  $regional_discount 1    $price_discount 1

I just don't what is wrong with the code, as I can extract the data line by line, but just can't total it, as I can't find a way of totalling the columns in the variable that works.

Note; the fields can be either percentages, currency or null values.

I am also not quite sure what @amount means, but assume it just extracts the numerical value - I've just copied it without actually knowing what it does!

Any further help would be most appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hey @resistme, mind providing more information in the question? Code that's being used for the generation, libraries being run, language you using (I'm guessing PHP from a glance)

Comment: Rather than expressing your frustration that lots of things you tried have failed for different reasons, it would be better to focus on one thing that failed and establish the reason for that. If you can reduce it to a simple question, you're much more likely to get a helpful answer.

Comment: thanks -I've updated the question breaking it down with more details to make it more succinct. I